# Check if akka actor exists in a cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-persistence

```
public void actorExists() throw ActorNotFound{  
FiniteDuration duration = Duration.create(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String actorPath = "akka://test/studentid";
        Await.result(actorSystem.actorSelection(actorPath).resolveOne(new Timeout(duration)), duration);
        return true;
}
```

This code is able to identify actors in local node but not from cluster. If no actor exist in local node it throws actor not found exception if exist it return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public boolean actorExists(String deviceId) throws Exception {
        for (Member member : cluster.state().getMembers()) {
            try {
                String actorPath = member.address() + "/test/studentid";
                FiniteDuration duration = Duration.create(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Await.result(actorSystem.actorSelection(actorPath).resolveOne(new Timeout(duration)), duration);
            } catch (ActorNotFound exception) {
                continue;
            }
            return true;
        }
        throw new ActorNotFound(null);
    }
```